# How can I change/edit Jenkins default message on login?

Tags: view, jenkins, permissions, edit

When a user logins in Jenkins with no View Permissions but with only Overall Read Permissions "Welcome to Jenkins!" this message flashes.
How can We edit this according to our requirement.Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a way to customize the UI message in Jenkins. The message "Welcome to Jenkins" is a default message you get it from the "ALL View"[ more in depth it is retrieved from the language properties from a file noJob.jelly ] Modifying it is not a good idea. 
As a work around you can always create another view and make that a default view from the `Manage Jenkins > Configure System` and select `Default view` option. You can add a custom message in this new view as you like... The draw back is even the users who have access will be defaulted to this default view. Hope this helps. 
This is how it will look..

[image]

Comment: Thanks VSK for quick reply.I exactly require the same type of screenshot you attached.
I have created one test view as told by you.
But I am not able to find noJob.jelly file.
Here is the path of my /var/lib/jenkins/ directory

jobs/  nodes/  plugins/  scriptler/  secrets/  updates/  userContent/  users/  workspace/

Please guide me to the particular file.

Thanks.

Comment: Do not edit the file !.. since you have created a test view Add a description to it. It should suffice. Make this test view as a default view from the manage jenkins > configure system

Comment: Thanks VSK.
Can you please help me out in changing font size of the custom message?I tried editing config.xml file but didn't help?